# Center all elements in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to build a simple registration form with only a few elements, and I want
to make all the elements be centered.

but when I combine it with bootstrap all my elements getting smaller, for example when I have
element with a width of 100%, when using the "centered" class it will become 25%.

can anyone help me figure out which bootstrap class should I use to center all elements? Because
using regular CSS and bootstrap is not a good combination apparently...
something like:

```css
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 70%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container center">
  * HTML tags goes here.... */
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your complete code!

Comment: how will this help? i just want to know how to do that with bootstrap...

Comment: I have added the answer, with respect to the provided code...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```css
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container center centered">
  * HTML tags goes here.... */
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want use pure css then You could use something like

```js
.layout {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100 vh
  height: 100 vw;
  display: grid;
  place - items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='layout'>
  <div class='form'>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will do the trick for you.